# jQuery Alert Only Working in Firefox and Not Chrome, Edge or IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Web developer newbie over here, but I'm trying to experiment with some jQuery Alerts in ASP.net and noticed that for some reason the code below is only working with Firefox.  It doesn't work with Chrome, Edge or even IE.  I ran the developer part of Chrome to look for errors and it's basically clean with no errors at all.  I tried pasting my full code below for inspection.  Can anyone see any obvious flaws that would cause this not to work?  The person in the YouTube video was using Chrome so it's a bit strange.  Here's the link:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTZjhCH80Zg  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
     <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" EnableSessionState="True" CodeFile="Default3.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default3"  %>

     <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head>
         <title>jquery expand textbox on focus using asp.net</title>


         <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
         <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- jQuery CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            $('#myAlert').show('fade');

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
            }, 2000);

        });

        $('#linkClose').click(function () {
            $('#myAlert').hide('fade');

        });

    });
</script>

     </head>
     <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">

         <br />
         <br />
         <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" class="btn btn-primary"/>

         <div id="myAlert" class="alert alert-success collapse">
           <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
           <strong>Button successfully clicked</strong>
         </div>

             </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.min.js` do the same thing. Same with `jquery-ui.css` and `jquery-ui.min.css`, `ui.structure.css` and `jquery-ui.structure.min.css`. Not sure this is your issue, but cleaning up redundancies won't hurt. `.min` means the file has been minified https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I see so many things in these examples that I just got into the habit of including everything since I don't know what's what.  I'll go ahead and remove those redundant references.  I figured out the answer to this problem in the end, I needed to do a return false; statement because ASP.net apparently tries to reload the form otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out what was going on here, ASP.net gets a little fickle with this type of stuff and tries to reload after the script fires. The solution is to include "return false;" (without the quotes) after the setTimeout function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
        $('#myAlert').show('fade');

        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#myAlert').hide('fade');
        }, 2000);
        return false;   //<------This here is the trick!

    });

    $('#linkClose').click(function () {
        $('#myAlert').hide('fade');

    });

});
</script>
```